# Hashtag key not working

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, input-languages, language-pack

On my keyboard, I am not able to type the `#`, which is typed using `shift`+`3`.( I had to copy-paste this one from google)

I don't know what happened, but it stopped working. I think it used to work earlier.

What I have figured out and tried:

- It is definitely not a keyboard problem. I have switched between keyboards and it still doesn't work.
- It doesn't work even when using the on-screen keyboard
- I have tried updating the keyboard drivers from Device Manager, but it says that drivers are up-to-date.
- I have only one language pack which is English (US). This is what my language settings look like:
  [image]

I tried everything given here- [https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-wont-type-hashtag/fc7b7882-d022-4b3b-a303-fc176bfbf850#:~:text=Press%20Windows%20key%20from%20the,the%20Hardware%20and%20Device%20Troubleshooter](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-wont-type-hashtag/fc7b7882-d022-4b3b-a303-fc176bfbf850#:%7E:text=Press%20Windows%20key%20from%20the,the%20Hardware%20and%20Device%20Troubleshooter),
but nothing works.

Some other points:

- I use Windows 10 Pro.
- All other keys work absolutely fine.

Can anybody suggest anything to help? What is going wrong?

Edit: Got it, it was caused Autohotkey. I fixed it, and the key works again `###################################`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#` key may have been remapped.

Run `regedit` and navigate to the registry key
`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout`.

Check if you have any items inside this key besides `(Default)`.
I do not refer to the sub-keys `DosKeybCodes` and `DosKeybIDs`.

If you find any such items, right-click `Keyboard Layout` and select
"Export" to backup the key as a `.reg` file, then delete these items
and reboot.

Comment: I got it! It was nothing to do with the registry, my registry was exactly what you described. The problem was caused by AutoHotKey. I have setup my daily driver ahk script to run at startup and I had put some weird hotkey command in it including the`#`. I deleted that line, and reloaded the script, and BOOM! It started working again. So it was a key remap, though not the way you thought...